# Listener between Fragment and Fragment (or Activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, lambda, interface, kotlin

Is there any better clean way to put a listener inside a Fragment?

```
class FooFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var listener: (Int) -> Unit

        fun newInstance(listener: (Int) -> Unit): FooFragment {
            Companion.listener = listener
            return FooFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foo, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            listener(1234)
        }
    }
}
```

The call is so tidy...

```
FooFragment.newInstance {
    // Do something
}
```

I know this code have problems due to maybe I lose the listener when the `Fragment` is recreated and that the standard way is using the `onAttach(context: Context?)` way.

But I want to create a new instance of the `FooFragment` from other `Fragment` (not an `Activity`). I could use something like this:

```
private var listener: Listener? = null

interface Listener {
    fun onFooClicked()
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    // listener = context as Listener
    fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.fFooParent) as Listener
}
```

But this piece of code inside the `onAttach(context: Context?)` method inside the `FooFragment`, would be counterproductive due to I do not want that the FooFragment knows anything of the class who insntantiates it. Moreover, I would like that it could be a `Fragment` or an `Activity`.

Comment: Why not just use `LocalBroadcastManager` and send and receive broadcasts? That's the recommended way to communicate among components.

Comment: It is a good idea, but I would like to avoid boilerplate

Comment: Doing what you're doing is pretty boilerplate. Just make a helper method that takes the `Int` argument and passes that as an extra in your broadcasts.

Comment: you can use `parentFragment as Listener` and use `childFragmentManager` when creating the Fragment that way the fragment knows nothing about the fragment that created it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crate a baseActivity which implements the listener

```
class BaseFragmentActivity:AppCompatActivity(), FooFragment.Listener{}
```

then extend `class YouFragmentActivity : BaseFragmentActivity`

then it will make sure that every fragment hosting activity is equipped with container then you can get the reference as `BaseFragmentActivity`

You can replace `AppCompatActivity` with `BaseActivity` where `BaseActivity :AppCompatActivity`

Comment: It crashes if I try to implement the interface in a `Fragment`. On the other hand, I do not want to make a base activity with many methods to override in their children. This is not a good practice...

Comment: Because I would have to implement the methods in each `Activity` beside the base activity and how I would name all those similar listener methods? Thanks, for sure it is a solution, but I would like to implement something cleaner

Comment: you can have a inner class reference of listener and create a setter in base activity which can accept a reference and set it,  it'll work polymorphic way, the cast to base activity will give you the access to reference to invoke methods (or you can call the method if you go with the answer) and I believe its a clean way, I would love to see some reference or docs where it says it isn't. although it's your choice

Comment: I could implement the interface within a Fragment?

Comment: you can create a separate interface , instead of inner class and follow the same approach with `baseFragment` class

Comment: look at [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment) class , you will see the number of interfaces to communicate with any type of fragment and android OS

Comment: Using static listeners is definitely a bad practice. Thank you @Pavneet_Singh